# Why is my code not spawning two processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

My code is not spawning 2 processes, and I have no idea why. I'm using Process from multiprocessing python library.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def dummy():
    while True:
        print(os.getpid())

p1 = Process(target=dummy())
p2 = Process(target=dummy())
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Expected result: 2 processes created - visible in windows 7 task manager as well as I am having 2 different process id printed by my code

Actual Result:
Only one python process running, only one process id is being printed out.

```
3480
3480
3480
```

Comment: The `while` loop is blocking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code isn't doing what you *think* it's doing.  On the first of these lines:

```
p1 = Process(target=dummy())
```

you're *calling* the `dummy()` function.  If you add some print statements, you'll see that you never go beyond this line.  Because calling `dummy()` starts an infinite loop in the *main* process, and the loop just prints the main process's pid forever.

Do this instead:

```
p1 = Process(target=dummy)
p2 = Process(target=dummy)
```

That is, don't *invoke* `dummy`, just pass the function object.  Then the later

```
p1.start()
```

(etc) will invoke `dummy()` in a new process, which is what you intended.

Comment: Would it be required to always use `if __name__ == '__main__':` with multiprocessing? Without having code inside this I am getting runtime error: `RuntimeErrorRuntimeError: : 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:
`

Comment: If you're running on Windows, you'll also need to put the mp code under the guard of an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.  Read the docs.  https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html and search for "Safe importing of main module"